# Images stacked on top of each other only in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, gallery

I have a small side scrolling gallery at [sidenote.hu/cellwars/pagez/screenshots/](http://sidenote.hu/cellwars/pagez/screenshots/), which displays correctly in all major browsers (Firefox, Safari, Opera, IE9) but not in Google Chrome.

In Chrome all images are displayed stacked into one column, so the side scrolling gallery is broken:

[image][image]

left: Firefox 15.0, right: Google Chrome 21.0.1180.83

Unfortunately I'm not familiar with JavaScript, but I'm familiar with CSS, and I've tried everything I could think of, but nothing helped. All sources can be found on the linked website.

Comment: add screenshot .not getting the problem

Comment: It was fine on my Chrome 11. Broken on Chrome 21.

Comment: see the i fixed in a few extent but problem in your code is auto dynamic mergin-left... i am looking into it :-)

Comment: 100000000 is to much for chrome to handle. 1000000 is just fine. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making your #image-holder wide enough. I made it 1680px wide and now the gallery works perfectly fine in Chrome 21. Of course you need to set the width according to the specific images you have in the gallery.

Edit: I see you had already set it to 100000000px. Seems like that was too much for the new Chrome. Works fine with one zero less.

Comment: two zero digits less, in my case.

Comment: So, setting an exact width according to the actual content (i.e. the images in the gallery) would probably be the safest choice instead of a huge "magic" width value.

Comment: @mkataja Solved the problem. Thank you!